# How to resolve the Error in f(x, ...) : unused argument (x)

Tags: r, function, variables, plot, integrate

```
f <- function(x) {((1/2)*((4*x)-1)*exp(-(1/2)*((3*x)+(2*x^2))))};
f   # order of arguments reversed 
h <- function(x) integrate(f, lower=0, upper=Inf, x=x)$value;
h 
g <- Vectorize(h);
g 
x <- seq(0,100)
plot(x,g(x), xlab="x", ylab="y", col="blue")
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use the code below

```
h <- function(x) integrate(f, lower=0, upper=Inf)$value;
```